# Configure heap size for javafx native packaged app

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I created a java application in netbeans using some existing jars(added as libraries). Then i created the native exe installer. I am not sure how I can allow the end users to change the heap size( May be point them to edit a configuration file). What can be the best way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change how you launch the app by adding a script that first runs that sets some environment vars (eg XMX) that is then consumed by the exe when it starts Java.

Comment: How do you "let the exe consume the environment vars"? (or the script?!?)